# Name of discrete transform $f(x)=\sum a(n) \exp(-x a(n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Is there a way to express the following transform (and perhaps its inverse) in terms of known discrete transforms?  For $a_i>0$ and $\sum_i a_i=1$ we have

$$f(x)=\sum_i^n a(i) \exp(-x a(i))$$

Equivalently, with $x=-\log y$

$$f(y)=\sum_i^n a(i) y^{a(i)}$$

The continuous version [can be represented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242534/inverse-of-integral-transform-fs-int-0-infty-gx-exp-s-gx-mathbbdx/4244315#4244315) in terms of Laplace transform as follows

$$f(t)=\int_0^\infty g(i) \exp(-t g(i))=\mathcal{L}(yg^{-1}(y)')$$

However, this involves functional inverse of $g$ which is undefined in the discrete case.

I'm looking for something I can leverage in practice to invert this for a vector $(b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ with $n\approx 10000$. Find $(t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ such that $f(t_0),f(t_1),\ldots,f(t_n)=(b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_n)$

Motivation: this transform [maps](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355) eigenvalues of quadratic Q to loss trajectory of gradient descent on Q, where $a(i)$ gives $i$th eigenvalue of $Q$ and $f(t)$ gives loss after $t$ steps.

Comment: For only 10000 terms, it should be easy to transform term by term and sum. Each term gives $(a_i+s)^{-1}$

Comment: To invert this numerically, I can turn this problem into 10000 $f(t)=b_i$ equations and solve them independently using a generic root finder. However I'm wondering if there's a problem specific approach that's faster

Comment: If you can evaluate the series involved in $f(s)$, you'll have a solution. Whether this can be done definitely depends on the $a_i$. Your smallest eigenvalue will dominate at large $x$. There, your inverse is appriximately a logarithm. Maybe this could save computational time.

Comment: Playing [around](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/Published/forum-discrete-laplace-example.nb) with continuous version, if $a(i)=1/i$ then inverting $f(t)=b$ gives $t=1/b$. For that example it seems the fat tail dominates over the top eigenvalue

Comment: The fat tail is the lowest eigenvalue.

Comment: Right, at large $x$ only smallest eigenvalue matters. The interesting regime is $x<n$ where all eigenvalues matter. The $1/b$ solution obtained by approximating sum with integral with $a(i)=1/i$ and applying inverse Laplace transform is only valid for $x<n$

Comment: If we only want a numerical solution, there can be a way more efficient than solving 10,000 $f(t_i) = b_i$ independently. Since $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, we can start by sorting $b_i$'s, say $b_1 > b_2 >  \dots > b_{10000}$. Then $t_1 < \dots < t_{10000}$. We can locate all solutions simultaneously by a bisection search: start from a large interval and keep only the intervals that contain at least one $t_i$: suppose $(u, v)$ is an interval obtained from the bisection process, if $u < v$ and $[f(v), f(u)] \subset (b_{i+1}, b_{i})$, then we can discard $(u, v)$.

Comment: So the inverse transform is not much slower than forward, the question then becomes is whether forward transform can be computed faster than n^2 for n values of x